# Android FragmentActivity returns null in getActionBar()

Tags: java, android, null, android-actionbar

I have imported an Android sample project called HorizontalPaging in Android Studio and it works fine when I run it. But when I copied the code into my code, **I get a NULL pointer exception in getActionBar()**.

I have been reading about these problems the whole day but can't get it working. Tried copying the entire code from the sample's MainActivity into my project but no improvements so I am guessing that the problem is in some other file like manifest,styles,etc.

**MainActivity.java** copied from the sample project

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;


public class View_Tabs extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Load the UI from res/layout/activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.view_tabs);


    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab. We can also use
    // ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the Tab.

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });



    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter. Also
        // specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // callback (listener) for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }

}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, tell the ViewPager to switch to the corresponding page.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.tab_list).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.tab_map).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.tab_list).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 * This would be replaced with your application's content.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tab_fragment, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}



}
```

**my manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!-- TABS: While ViewPager will work on API 4 or above, tabs require an ActionBar. ActionBar is only
 available in API 11 or above. -->
<!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

.... 

    <activity
        android:name=".View_Tabs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**my styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- BEFORE <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">  -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Light" />




</resources>
```

**my gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile files('lib/gson-2.3.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try changing this :  `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` to this :  `final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: To use getSupportActionBar() I needed to change FragmentActivity to ActionBarActivity otherwise the casting to ActionBarActivity gives me cast error exception.  And also change import android.app.ActionBar  to  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar. This way the app runs OK but I still don't understand why the sample code works perfectly ONLY outside my project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity to have Actionbar with fragments.

If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend ActionBarActivity, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity (for more information, read Adding the Action Bar).

Still you can try this,

```
ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

More detail you can found here.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 1):

getActionBar() will return correct value only if you have the activity with a title bar. Make sure you have set a theme with titlebar for your activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

try this in Your maifest file

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```