# SQLite Android Has Stopped

Tags: android, android-studio

im just learning android programming and try following example from some tutorial to make sqlite

```
databasehelper.java
package simpleform.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentdb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABEL_STUDENT = "student";

public static final String ID            = "id";
public static final String NAME          = "name";
public static final String ADDRESS= "address";
public static final String BIRTH = "birth";

public static final String CREATE_TABEL_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABEL_STUDENT + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + NAME+ " TEXT, " + ADDRESS+ " TEXT, "
        + BIRTH + " DATE" + ")";

private static DataBaseHelper instance;

public static synchronized DataBaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    return instance;
}

private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABEL_STUDENT);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

When I am trying to run it on Android virtual Device , It says unfortunately , sqLite has stopped

Comment: post the error log

Comment: in andoid studio and emulator no log error, just message sqlite has been stopped, tried at xiaomi device here is the summary:
va.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.khoerul.simpleemployee/com.example.khoerul.simpleemployee.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)

Comment: There are multiple typo of TABEL_STUDENT in your code. Shouldn't it be TABLE_STUDENT? And judging from your error log, it seems you cannot start DB in your MainActivity, which causes NPE. You should post it too.

Comment: should have post the real code, kindly look at the answer below sir, thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Error \[Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar' on a null object reference\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144657/android-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-app-actionbar-on)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android FragmentActivity returns null in getActionBar()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581396/android-fragmentactivity-returns-null-in-getactionbar)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
  protected void setFragmentTitle(int resourseId) {
        setTitle(resourseId);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resourseId); 
    }
```

As pointed out by petey.